# how to add script and styles in mule anypoint studio

Tags: javascript, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

How can I add external JavaScript and css from root path in anypoint studio

I am rendering a html page using parse template in anypoint studio the html page contains a form tag .I want to add JavaScript and css files references in that html page like below.

```
  <script src="src/main/resources/jsfile1.js"></script>
    <h1>Salesforce data retrieval</h1>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        Object: <select name="object" >
            #[message.payload]
        </select>
        Field: <input type="text" name="field" />
        Search Key: <input type="text" name="searchKey" />
        Search Value: <input type="text"  name="searchValue" />
        <br/>
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id=jqxgrid>
    </div>
```

Update:If add like below error loading script [image: Error loading script]

Comment: Do not include "src/main/resources/" in your src-attribute, at runtime the contents of this folder will be available, not he whole structure

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you put these files in `src/main/resources` it should work if it doesn't you can try placing you entire `<script>` in the same html file and render it using **HTTP Static Resource Handler.**

Comment: the js files are plugins. I want to add so I can't add all js inside script tag.

Comment: The plugin must be hosted at some URL you can directly include them in your code  ***<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js</script>***

Comment: Any idea how it can be process to get working css/js file on MULE parse-template ?

Comment: You can acomplish this using HTTP Static Resource Handler.

Comment: all your css/js files should be in mule/src/resources